# How can I make the printer not turn the sheet if I print a single page?

Tags: printing, hplip

- OS: Arch Linux
- `uname -r`: 5.5.4-arch1-1
- `pacman -Q hplip`: hplip 1:3.19.12-1

I usually leave the setting for printing double-sided on "Long Edge" or whatever exactly it is called in English.

Printing a document which has only 1 page makes the printer print the document in double-sided mode, which is expected behavior. So the printer then prints one page of the document, turns the sheet, does not print anything on the empty page and then ejects it.

Is it possible to have the printer/driver automatically recognize that the document is only 1 page long and can get printed in single-sided mode, i.e. without the sheet turn?